# How can I download all stored procedures from a specific database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to download all stored procedures from a specific database.

There are around 130 stored procedures, and I can do it manually like by doing save as a file each one.

But is there any automatic option to download all ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1) Open SQL Server Management Studio
2) Select your database in the Object Explorer
3) Right click > Tasks > Generate Scripts

[image]

4) Select only stored procedures to be scripted out

[image]

5) Following the wizard through the steps; on the next screen, pick option `Single file per object` and define a directory where to put those files:

[image]

With those options, you get **one file per stored procedure**, stored in the directory of your choice.

Comment: Hey i want 130 separate files for each SP :( it is giving me only one file

Comment: @ashuthinks: wherever you like them to be! Step through the wizard - it will ask you whether you want one file for all stored procs, or one file per stored proc, and it will ask you where to store those...

Comment: @ashuthinks: see my third screenshot - is that what you're looking for??? **One file per object** ??

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in management studio - Right click the database you want and select tasks -> Generate scripts -> go through the wizard. You can then specify just stored procedures etc.

You can also use a script like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Test TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Code VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @Test (Code)
SELECT 'IF object_ID(N''[' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + Name + ']'') IS NOT NULL
          DROP PROCEDURE ['+ schema_name(schema_id) +' ].[' + Name + ']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) +CHAR(10) +
           OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) + CHAR(13) +CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            FROM sys.procedures
            WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0

DECLARE @lnCurrent INT, @lnMax INT
DECLARE @LongName VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @lnMax = MAX(Id) FROM @Test
SET @lnCurrent = 1
WHILE @lnCurrent <= @lnMax
      BEGIN
            SELECT @LongName = Code FROM @Test WHERE Id = @lnCurrent
            WHILE @LongName <> ''
               BEGIN
                   PRINT LEFT(@LongName,8000)
                   SET @LongName = SUBSTRING(@LongName, 8001, LEN(@LongName))
               END
            SET @lnCurrent = @lnCurrent + 1
      END
```

You can also shift+click to select all the stored procedures and you can then right-click and script them to a file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use DB pro (Visual Studio tools for Database) to do this too.
For more information check this - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2971/creating-a-visual-studio-database-project-for-an-existing-sql-server-database/

Edit: Updated the stale link.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is now dead.  Link-only answers are discouraged for exactly that reason.  If the answer were edited to include some content, it could be saved.